# Как растянуть картинку по ширине и высоте?

Tags: java, android, xml

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы картинка растянулась по высоте.
Я растянул ее по ширине, но нужно чтобы она растянулась по высоте сохраняя пропорции.
Вот что у меня получилось и не пойму как это поправить[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинки сами по себе 290px на 170px, создал 3 колонки и растянул их по ширине, а вот с высотой проблема.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: если это айтемы списка, нужна разметка айтема, куда эти картинки, собственно, помещаются, а не бесполезная в этом вопросе разметка экрана со списком

Answer (score 0):

Для списка в котором картинки в три столбика используй GridView.
[почитай тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

[и тут можешь почитать](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/gridview.php)

Answer (score 0):

Повторюсь, я новичок в java, начал наделю назад где то, мои потуги привели к следующему варианту для установки высоты.

main_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ru.site.api.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/main_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerView (@+id/list) принимает items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alt_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
            android:text="@string/loading" />

        <ru.site.api.myapplication.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Класс SquareImageView.java

```
public class SquareImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public static final String d = SquareImageView.class.getCanonicalName();

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Ширину у высоту я знаю, поэтому проще.
        int heightPercent = 171*100/291;
        int height = getMeasuredWidth() / 100 *  heightPercent;

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);
    }
}
```

В итоге получилось следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть вариант по проще, то подскажите как сделать.